# Relationship between Fragment.onCreate() and Activity.onCreate()

Tags: android, android-fragments

Dear fellow developers,

The relationship between a Fragment's onCreate() method and that of an Activity is not yet crystal clear to me. I'm attaching a Fragment to an Activity like this.

```
//happens in the Activity:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fragMan = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment dataModelFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag("data_model");
    if (dataModelFragment == null) {
        dataModelFragment = new DataModelFragment();
        fragMan.beginTransaction().add(dataModelFragment,"data_model").commit();
    }
    System.out.println("Executing Activity.onCreate()");
}
```

My Fragment's onCreate() has a Sysout.println() for testing purposes to see when exactly it executes. What makes me wonder is: why does the Activity's onCreate finish execution first, before even the Fragment's onCreate() is called? What happens is that the Sysout.println shown in the above code actually executes BEFORE the other Sysout.println, which is in the onCreate() of my Fragment. I would expect the Fragment's onCreate() to be executed before I add it to the Activity via the fragment transaction. Is it the way it is supposed to work? Or is the problem what I read in the docs that the commit() method does not execute immediately but places the fragment transaction only in the queue?

What I would like to achieve is this:

- I'm using a singleton instance of a Fragment as a data model to be retained across activity lifecycles.
- I'd like to add this fragment to the activity, then let this fragment perform its initialization (creating a database connection and loading the data into its data members)
- Finally this data from the fragment should be used with AdapterViews in the Activity's View.

So the three steps: initialize fragment with data, attach fragment to activity, create adapters in the activity from the fragment's data. My question: in which methods should these events occur to ensure the proper order of execution?

Many thanks!

Comment: **"why does the Activity's onCreate execute first, and why is the Fragment's onCreate() executing afterwards?"** - Huh? You're creating the `Fragment` inside the `Activity` `onCreate(...)` method. How could it possibly work the other way around?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not concrete enough in the way I formulated the question. My question more correctly sounds like: If I'm creating the Fragment from the Activity's onCreate() method, why does the complete Activity.onCreate() finish execution before even the Fragment's onCreate() was called? What happens is that the Sysout.println shown above actually executes BEFORE my other Sysout.println, which is in the onCreate method of my Fragment.

Comment: I suspect a clue might be in the name `FragmentTransaction` and like many 'transaction' mechanisms certain aspects are asynchronous. This seems to be a particularly good approach based on the fact that stalling the creation/start of an `Activity` is a bad idea (possible ANR scenario). Depending on what a `Fragment` needs to do during its creation/start, it would make sense for it to not hold up progress in its 'host' `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android `FragmentTransaction.Commit()` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29):

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

If you want your transaction to be processed immediately call `FragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions()` from your UI thread.